# PHP foreach loop is not working

Tags: php, foreach

I have following multiple select element in my html form (method - post). I want to convert $songs array to convert in ordered list.

```
<select name="songs" multiple>
  <option>song 1</option>
  <option>song 2</option>
  <option>song 3</option>
  <option>song 4</option>
  <option>song 5</option>
  <option>song 6</option>
  <option>song 7</option>
  <option>song 8</option>
  <option>song 9</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

I written following php code

```
 $songs = test_input($_POST["songs"]);
 foreach ($songs as $song) 
 {
   $songs .= "<li>$song</li>";
 };

 $songList = "Songs: <ol> $songs </ol> \r\n";
 echo $songList;

 function test_input($data)
 {
      $data = trim($data);
      $data = stripslashes($data);
      $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
      return $data;
 }
```

But it gives me an error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Someone please tell what's going wrong with this `foreach()` loop

---

If function test_input() returns `String` instead of `Array` then what should I do to convert `$songs` into ordered list?

Comment: var_dump($songs); before the foreach loop and let us know the result

Comment: Does `test_input()` return an array?

Comment: Can you show your select HTML form?

Comment: Without seeing the definition of `test_input`, we cannot answer this question.

Comment: You should remove the `;` at the end bracket of your foreach loop

Comment: You can't `foreach` over a string.  Your `test_input` suggests that's it's a string.

Comment: Then what should I do to convert it into an list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
<?php
$songs = $_POST["songs"];
//$songs = Array("one","two","three");
foreach ($songs as $song) 
{
   $songStr = test_input($song);
   $songsOut .= "<li>$songStr</li>";
};

$songList = "Songs: <ol> $songsOut </ol> \r\n";
echo $songList;

function test_input($data)
{
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>
```

The `test_input()` needs to be called separately on each item in the array, rather than on the array itself.

Are you sure that the post data actually is an array? I tested my code with a get string (so I could type it in the browser bar), and it requires the following syntax:

```
http://localhost/songs.php?songs[]=one&songs[]=two&songs[]=three
```

The `foreach` error message will account for the $POST associate array not returning an array of values, uncommenting the second line in my code will help debug this. If you post the code that generates the $POST we can check that also!

**Edit - changing the name of the multiple select element seems to work for me:**

```
<select name="songs[]" multiple>
  <option>song 1</option>
  <option>song 2</option>
  <option>song 3</option>
  <option>...</option>
</select>
```

see: [Multi-select to Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11426339/multi-select-to-array)

Comment: I have updated codes. still not working

Comment: @itsme see edit in post body

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are altering `$songs` as you loop through it. You should use a different variable for the html string:

```
 $songs = test_input($_POST["songs"]);
 $html = '';
 foreach ($songs as $song) 
 {
   $html .= "<li>$song</li>";
 }

 $songList = "Songs: <ol> $html </ol> \r\n";
 echo $songList;
```

Comment: Irrelevant. `foreach` operates on a copy of the array, and you although it's not particularly good practice, you can change the variable inside the loop without adverse effects.

Answer (score 0):

`test_input($_POST["songs"]);` should be an array, Your code is perfect. `test_input($_POST["songs"]);` but should return an array

Check if your `$songs` is array by using the function `is_array()`

```
$songs = array('a','b');
    if (is_array($songs))
    {
         foreach ($songs as $song) 
         {
           $songs .= "<li>$song</li>";
         }
    }else{
     echo "its not an array";
    }
$songList = "Songs: <ol> $songs </ol> \r\n";
echo $songList;`  //output:  Songs: <ol> Array<li>a</li><li>b</li> </ol>
```